# The online version of VS Code is unable to open projects via SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to use the local version of VS Code on macOS to open projects on any host using SSH, but it seems that this method does not work on the online version of VS Code, i.e. https://vscode.dev/.

When I use vscode.dev to open a remote project, only three options are available: "Open from Azure", "Open from GitHub", and "Pull from GitHub". I am unable to input any IP address for an SSH connection.

Is there a solution to this problem, or is this a limitation of vscode.dev?

Thank!